# Stopped QRunnable cause Mainwindow un-closable

Tags: multithreading, qt

- Platform: Qt 4.8.2 (built from source using MinGW x64), Win 7

I'm using QRunnable to separate long running tasks from main GUI thread, and I sometimes experience random crash/strange behavior with no traceable errors. Please help to provide suggestions on what/how to debug. Thanks

**Runner class**:  multi-inherit for signal/slot connection to main window

```
class MyRunner : public QObject, public  QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT
Q_SIGNALS:
    void feedbackLog(QString text);
    void finished();
public:
    explicit MyRunner(/* some args */) { /* some initialization */ }

    void run() {
        stopped_ = false;
        for (int run = 0; run < SOME_COUNT; run++) {

            Q_EMIT feedbackLog("Resetting everything ...");
            if (stopped_) return;

            /* start the daily interaction until the epidemic is over */
            do
            {
                if (stopped_) return;
                lengthySubTaskA();
                if (stopped_) return;
                lengthySubTaskB();
                if (stopped_) return;
                lengthySubTaskC();
            }
            while (conditionNotReached());
        } // end: for(run)
        stopped_ = true;
        Q_EMIT finished();
    }
    bool isStopped() { return stopped_; }
public Q_SLOTS:
    void stop() {
        Q_EMIT feedbackLog("Cancel ...");
        stopped_ = true;
    }
private:
    bool stopped_;
    /** other class members follow */
};
```

**MainWindow segment**

```
void MainWindow::callMyRunnable() {
    runner_ = new MyRunner(/* args */); // runner_ is class member */
    runner_->setAutoDelete(true); // (a)
    progress_dialog_ = new QProgressDialog("Running", "Cancel", 0, 0, this);
    progress_dialog_->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

    connect(runner_, SIGNAL(feedbackLog(QString)), SLOT(logMessage(QString)));
    connect(runner_, SIGNAL(finished()),           SLOT(endLengthyJob()));
    connect(runner_, SIGNAL(finished()), progress_dialog_, SLOT(close()));
    connect(progress_dialog_, SIGNAL(canceled()), runner_, SLOT(stop()));
    connect(progress_dialog_, SIGNAL(canceled()), SLOT(endLengthyJob()));

    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(runner_);
    progress_dialog_->show();
    /* flu_runner_->deleteLater(); */ // (b)
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e) {
     if (runner_ && !runner_->isStopped()) runner_->stop(); // (c)
     if (QThreadPool::globalInstance()->activeThreadCount())
     {
         /* display a dialog to notify user about shutdown */
         Dialog::WaitDialog dlg(5 * 1000);
         dlg.exec();
     }
     event->accept();
} // end_event(MainWindow::closeEvent)
```

1) If I disable autodelete at (a), should I add statement (b) to prevent leaking? Or any better way to handle the leaking?

2) Sometimes, when the Runnable task completed, I cannot close the app normally (neither [x] button nor Alt-F4 work), and I have to kill the app from within QtCreator (I'm debugging, right?). What would be possible cause to this?

[Edit]: 3) For un-closable mainwindow, sometimes it happens after I cancelled the task handled by MyRunner class, will this be a possible cause?

[Edit]: I added qDebug() statement around (c), and found that it stop at (c) and refuse to proceed to display the waiting dialog in case if the [x] button is not responding.

Thanks.

Comment: Why runner_ and progress_dialog_ are class members - are you accessing them anywhere else? They should be local variables by logic of the program, since each callMyRunnable() effectively resets those pointers. If you need to access them from anywhere else, that might be a source of the problem, otherwise, I would suggest to make them local to ensure those pointers are not used outside of callMyRunnable()

Comment: For runner_, I need to stop the spawned thread in case the user close the main window by [x] button, pls check my close-event and see statement (c) in my post. The task run by runner_ can take hours to stop if I just using QThreadPool::waitForDone(), which will freeze my app.

Comment: For progress_dialog_, I cannot use modal dialog as I want user to interact some widgets on the main windows. If I use dialog.show() with local variable, it quickly disappear, leaving no chance for user to cancel the task.

Comment: Ok, but if you enter callMyRunnable() two times, the first runner will not be accessible anymore. If you need to access it - you need some container of pointers for storing them - like std::vector<MyRunner*>, not MyRunner*.

Comment: If there is single progress dialog/runner - create it in constructor and delete it in destructor, only access them in callMyRunnable(). If you need multiple runners/dialogs - you will need some container for them.

Comment: callMyRunnable is triggered from the menu, and I disable the menu just before invoking callMyRunnable(), so the user should not have chance to re-enter callMyRunnable() immediately. The runner_ will only interact with CallMyRunnable() and windows::closeEvent, so I expect using just one variable instead of a list should be enough

Comment: `/* start the daily interaction until the epidemic is over */` o_O

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved by changing the 'close-strategy' of the mainwindow: remove 'auto-killing' and force user to wait for spawned thread. Variables `runner_` and `progress_dialog_` are now localized to the function `callMyRunnable()`